# Optimizing C for loops

Tags: c, linux, loops, optimization

I have been trying to optimize my program so far I got down to 8 seconds but my goal its to make it less than 5 seconds. What else could I change in my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N_TIMES 600000
#define ARRAY_SIZE 10000

int main(void) {
    double *array = calloc(ARRAY_SIZE, sizeof(double));
    double sum = 0;
    int i, j;

    printf("CS201 - Asgmt 4 - your name\n");

    for (i = 0; i < N_TIMES; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j = j + 20) {
            sum = sum + array[j] + array[j+1] + array[j+2] + array[j+3] +
                  array[j+4] + array[j+5] + array[j+6] + array[j+7] +
                  array[j+8] + array[j+9] + array[j+10] + array[j+11] +
                  array[j+12] + array[j+13] + array[j+14] + array[j+15] +
                  array[j+16] + array[j+17] + array[j+18] + array[j+19];
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use dynamic memory allocation when you know the size at compile time.

Comment: Code optimization is off-topic. Try codereview, maybe.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: irrelevant for speeding up the program, really. that'd be an O(1) operation.

Comment: I am obligated since my teacher want us to get array size using double *array = calloc(ARRAY_SIZE, sizeof(double));

Comment: The program use to be at 22 seconds I brought it down to 8 seconds I think Im in the right direction right?

Comment: @MarcB and that is why it is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: try loop blocking/tiling, unrolling, parallel reduction

Comment: Do not abuse the [tag:review] tag like you just did. Read it's description and notice it's written quite explicit that it's not meant for your question.

Comment: Indent your code properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove all of the meaningless process.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    printf("CS201 - Asgmt 4 - your name\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks to enjoy my day

Comment: Technically this is the correct answer. Since `sum` is never returned or output, there's no point in the whole process.

Comment: I know but we are supposed to run this program in a linux server using time a04, a04 beign the name of the program and the terminal will return the times it took for the addition

Comment: is there a way we can manually optimize this code can you help me

Comment: What is "optimize"? I think one of it is removing code that virtually do nothing and wastes CPU time. How foolish assignment this is!

Comment: The point of this assignment is that when we run time "name of program " we will get a time less than 5 seconds the for loop that I unrolled manually use to  be

Comment: for (j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j++) {
   sum += array[j];
   }

Comment: but by adding an unrolling sequence to the loop we can do addition separately therefore getting the time executed by the program from 22 seconds to 8 seconds so far

Answer (score 1):

Let the optimizer do the optimization for you.

I took the code and pasted it into `a.c`.

```
$ gcc a.c -o a
$ time ./a
CS201 - Asgmt 4 - your name

real    0m7.128s
user    0m7.032s
sys     0m0.004s
$ gcc -O2  a.c   -o a
$ time ./a
CS201 - Asgmt 4 - your name

real    0m0.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
$
```

Jokes aside, unrolling is good.

Switching the loops may help if the data is larger than the cache.
On my computer it didn't make any noticable difference (the data is only 80kb).

Threading could be the next step. That way you can use more than one core.

If your server is anything like my home computer (which has a really good graphics card), then you would get the best result if you used that. 
A popular library for using the graphics card to do calculations is CUDA.

Comment: I cant do what mikeCat said becuase we are supposed to run this program in a linux server using time a04, a04 beign the name of the program and the terminal will return the times it took for the addition

Comment: Are you allowed to add optimizer flags to the compile command?

Comment: it needs to have the code I have but some how optimize the loops, I tried to optimize the loop buy unrolling the loop

Comment: I didn't change the code at all. I just added an optimizer flag.

Comment: no I wish we have to manually optimize the code :(

Comment: for real, is there a way to see the optimization code ??

Comment: The optimizer realized that the result was never used, so it threw away the loop. If you reverted the resulting program back to C code it would look as MikeCATs answer.

Comment: man that sucks :( I have no idea how to optimize this code anymore, and our teacher says that we have to do it manually since otherwise will happen what u describe adding an optimizer flag

Comment: hey guys thanks for those who tried to help me. I figured using pointers and indeed bump it down to 4.30 some which is super good for me here is how I did it for (int i = 0; i < N_TIMES; i++) {
double *j=array;


for(; j<&array[ARRAY_SIZE];j+=10){
    sum += j[0]+j[1]+j[2]+j[3]+j[4]+j[5]+j[6]+j[7]+j[8]+j[9];
}
 }

Answer (score 1):

`calloc` returns an array initialized with zero bytes. Considering that your machine probably uses IEEE 754 binary floats, all `double` values in that array are `0.0`.

Now, what you're doing is essentially repeating 300000000 times `sum = sum + 0.0 + 0.0 + 0.0 + 0.0 + 0.0 + 0.0 + 0.0 + 0.0 + 0.0 + 0.0 + 0.0 + 0.0 + 0.0 + 0.0 + 0.0 + 0.0 + 0.0 + 0.0 + 0.0 + 0.0`.

Thus **if** you need `sum`, we can optimize the loop to:

```
sum = 0.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a multiply instruction?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N_TIMES 600000
#define ARRAY_SIZE 10000

int main (void){
    double *array = calloc(ARRAY_SIZE, sizeof(double));
    double sum = 0;
    int i, j;

    printf("CS201 - Asgmt 4 - your name\n");
    for (i = 0; i < N_TIMES; i+=N_TIMES) {
        for (j = 0; j < ARRAY_SIZE; j=j+20) {
            sum = sum + array[j] + array[j+1] + array[j+2] + array[j+3] + array[j+4] + array[j+5] + array[j+6] + array[j+7] + array[j+8] + array[j+9] + array[j+10] +   array[j+11] + array[j+12] +array[j+13] + array[j+14] + array[j+15] + array[j+16]   + array[j+17] + array[j+18] + array[j+19];
        }
        sum *=N_TIMES;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's try changing the algorithm as that typically gives the best results.

**Method #1.**
As all memory is the allocated memory is initialized to zero due to calloc(), and it is never assigned another value, each double in the allocated array will have a value of 0.0.  Thus the sum of all the doubles in the allocated memory is always 0.0.

**Method #2.**
The sum of all the elements is not changing from one iteration to the next.  So, calculate the sum once and then multiply it N_TIMES.

Some other options (if the above are not acceptable):

**Method #3.**
If you must iterate through loops each time, then let's help the compiler do the calculations in parallel so that the result of one addition has none-to-minimal impact on the next.  To this end, organize the additions in the inner loop as follows ...

```
                    tmp[0] = array[j] + array[j+1];
                    tmp[1] = array[j+2] + array[j+3];
                    tmp[2] = array[j+4] + array[j+5];
                    tmp[3] = array[j+6] + array[j+7];
                    tmp[4] = array[j+8] + array[j+9];
                    tmp[5] = array[j+10] + array[j+11];
                    tmp[6] = array[j+12] + array[j+13];
                    tmp[7] = array[j+14] + array[j+15];
                    tmp[8] = array[j+16] + array[j+17];
                    tmp[9] = array[j+18] + array[j+19];

                    tmp[0] += tmp[1];
                    tmp[2] += tmp[3];
                    tmp[4] += tmp[5];
                    tmp[6] += tmp[7];
                    tmp[8] += tmp[9];

                    tmp[0] += tmp[2];
                    tmp[4] += tmp[6];

                    tmp[0] += tmp[4];
                    sum += (tmp[8] + tmp[0]);
```

On my machine this improved things by about 17% (6.8 seconds to 5.6 seconds) (gcc file.c -o file).

**Method #4.**
Fine tune the parallellization from method #3.

**Method #5.**
Try enabling SSE math if both your compiler and target machine support it if it is not already enabled.

```
gcc -mfpmath=sse file.c -o file
```

On my machine, this cuts the execution time down further (from 5.6 seconds to 5.4)

**Method #6.**
Again, if both your compiler and target machine support it, try writing your inner loop to take advantage of vectorization--so that it can do more than one addition at once.

**Method #7.**
Turn on your compiler's optimization flags.

```
gcc -mfpmath=sse -O2 file.c -o file
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, the code invokes undefined behavior because all bits 0 is not necessarily a valid representation for `double` type.  The result is not used, but using an invalid `double` could cause a system defined exception to be triggered.

On a computer with IEEE.754 floats, all bits 0 is the representation of `0.0`. Adding all these numbers will produce the value `0.0`, repeating the process `N_TIMES` times makes no difference.

If you are required to allocate the memory with `calloc()`, do that, but the rest of the computation is useless:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N_TIMES 600000
#define ARRAY_SIZE 10000

int main(void) {
    double *array = calloc(ARRAY_SIZE, sizeof(double));

    printf("CS201 - Asgmt 4 - your name\n");

    free(array);  // you might want to free the array for good style

    return 0;
}
```